# Displaying USNG Coordinates in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinates, united-states

I need to display points in ArcMap using a spreadsheet with United States National Grid (USNG) Coordinates. I have previously done it with Lat/Longs where I convert the spreadsheet to a table, right-click on the table and select 'Display XY Data'.

Is there a way to map the points using the USNG Coordinates?

Comment: Please explain what "USNG" coordinates are.

Comment: United States National Grid (USNG)

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to provide any requested clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

This blog post from @ESRI gives the best path to go. There are some nuances that can happen on a state-by-state basis.

[MGRS/USNG Coordinates to Web Map Made Easy](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-online/defense/mgrs-usng-coordinates-to-web-map-made-easy/)

You will want to use the default/build-in MGRS (Military Grid Reference System) Geocoder/Locator.